# Alternative to "Vote Up Down" module for?

Tags: 7

Is there any other module like [vote_up_down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down), but for Drupal 7? This one has a development version but as the author says it is unstable.

> 7.x (unstable, on development, do not use this version for production)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) module for rating. Or the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module. Some more details about these modules (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar):

  > ... adds a clean, attractive voting widget to nodes and comments and any entity. It features:
  >
  > - jQuery rollover effects and AJAX no-reload voting
  > - Configurable star sets
  > - Graceful degradation to an HTML rating form when JavaScript is turned off
  > - Support for anonymous voters
  > - Spam protection to keep users from filling your DB with bogus votes
  > - Easy-to-use integration with Views module for lists sorted by rating, or filtered by min/max ratings
  > - A Fivestar CCK field for use in custom node types
  > - An easy-to-use Form API element type for use in other modules
  > - Compatible with all versions of jQuery (1.0 - 1.8)
- [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate):

  > ... provides flexible voting widgets for nodes and comments. "*The cck model for voting with Drupal*".